# PHP exec and parameter

Tags: php, c++, exec, exe

I need to use a parameter in an .exe file

```
foreach ($pieces as $value) {
$output = 0;
$output = exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\VWM\\C++ Scripts\\getStemWord.exe $value");  
var_dump($output);      
}
```

$value is string from the form.

and my getStemWord.cpp

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv []) {
string word(argv[1]);
cout  << word;
return 0;
}
```

in my php page I see

> string(0) ""

Now I have a solution

```
$output = exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\VWM\\C++ Scripts && getStemWord.exe $value");
```

Comment: Does it show the parameter when started outside PHP?

Comment: If I write a `string word= "word"`  and in php will be `$output = exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\VWM\\C++ Scripts\\getStemWord.exe"); `
on webside will be `string(4) "word" `

Comment: But did you test it outside PHP?

Comment: Just now I tried it and it works outside PHP

Comment: I don't know where is a problem